# Including a Map in the container

Tags: html

I have a container with few forms and a Map in it. I would like to increase the size of the full container and position the map in right/left side of it.But If I modify the column or row the map moves to bottom of the container. How can I feed the map properly ?

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="street">Event Name</label> <br>
      <p>
        <?php  echo $_SESSION['current_event_name']; ?> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="street">Event2</label> <br>
      <p>
        <?php  echo $_SESSION['current_event_descr']; ?> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="street">Event3</label> <br>
      <p>
        <?php  echo $_SESSION['current_event_hobby']; ?> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="street">Event 4</label> <br>
      <p>
        <?php  echo $_SESSION['current_event_date']; ?> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="street">Event Time</label> <br>
      <p>
        <?php  echo $_SESSION['current_event_time_start']." to ".$_SESSION['current_event_time_start']; ?> </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-6">
    <p> Maps </p>
    <div id="map-container" class="z-depth-1" style="height: 1800px; width: 200px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to define this kind of style on FIRST 'col-6' div:

```
float: left;
width: 50%;
```

Comment: you mean for the map style or for the forms

Comment: I mean for the form

Comment: <div class="col-6" style="float: left; width:50%;"> something like this right

Comment: Yes. Or you can define another class on 'col-6' element. Something like this: <div class="col-6 new-class">

Comment: the container looks the same..,there is no change

Comment: yes I have did the exact same thing..there is no change :(